# Carrying case for a device and some accessories

Tags: case

I'm looking for a storage case for the following collection of items (not including the ruler, which is just for reference in the photo):

[image]

The item on the left is a USB KVM adapter, it is about 1" depth; the rest is a collection of accessories I've built up. I've already picked up an [Amazon Basics Travel Case](http://amzn.com/B002VPE1QG), which is a perfect fit for the accessories but doesn't fit the adapter itself (disappointing; it is a nice little case):

[image]

It does have to be a hard case, other than that I don't have any real solid requirements for this one. Ideally:

- Hard shell, zipper preferred to clips.
- Under $50, but I'm somewhat flexible there.
- In the item photo above, the objects in the top row should be the easiest to access.
- Space for a couple more video adapters in the future. Doesn't really need space for anything else beyond what's in the picture, though.
- Can be opened without everything falling out; no loose storage.

Here are a few things I don't care about:

- Doesn't need to lock.
- Doesn't need to have a soft cloth exterior (although it does look nicer).
- Doesn't *need* internal padding like foam (it's OK if it does, but the device itself is already ruggedized and is not fragile).

I kind of want to stay away from custom-built cases for budget reasons.